# MDX Inverse Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, mdx, normal-distribution

How do I create an inverse normal distribution function in MDX? This would be the equivalent of the NORM.INV() function in Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a very good architecture, but it possible to call Excel functions from MDX in Analysis Services Multidimensional instances. I say it's not a good architecture because you have to install Excel on the server and there's some question about what version of Excel you have to install. My notes say that installing Excel 2003 or later should work but I haven't tested those notes in about 10 years. I suspect Office 365 install of Excel will not work. If you get it working then you will see an excel.exe process fire up as SSAS runs Excel functions out-of-process.

The list of Excel functions which are supported are not well documented. The [doc I have](http://web.archive.org/web/20090722011824/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178231(SQL.80).aspx) is from Analysis Services 2000 but I am fairly certain was still accurate per my testing as recently as Analysis Services 2008 (and is probably currently accurate still in Analysis Services 2017 and above).

Anyway, if you get this working, then the following MDX calculated member should work, I believe:

```
create member CurrentCube.[Measures].[test] as NormInv(0.908789, 40, 1.5);
```

Incidentally, if you expand the Assemblies folder under your SSAS instance in SSMS, you will see an ExcelMDX assembly which I believe is the bridge to Excel. That comes pre-installed.

Another option is that the DAX language has a [NORM.INV function](https://dax.guide/norm-inv/) which will have much better performance characteristics as it's natively implemented. It appears this function is available in Analysis Services 2019 per the dax.guide website and I suspect that means a DAX query against a Multidimensional model would be able to use this function like:

```
evaluate row("My NORM.INV Calc",Norm.Inv(0.908789, 40, 1.5))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This is very helpful